# Is it possible to use the :put Ex command using column numbers?

Tags: ex-mode, mark

The documentation for `:put` says that the command accepts a line. That is, it puts the content after the line specified. Is it possible to put the content at a particular mark?

For example, say I am in the middle of refactoring an anonymous JavaScript function into a named JavaScript function. I have the following in-process code (mid-refactoring), and I want to move the anonymous function to before the semi-colon on line 2.

```
function createClickListener(element) {
    return ;
}

var listener = createClickListener(element);
element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert("You clicked the element!");
}, false);
```

In normal mode, I can place my cursor at the beginning of `f` in the anonymous function, type `"fc/}/e` (followed by the `<enter>` key) to cut the anonymous function into the named register `f` and enter insert mode, and then type `listener`.

However, in order to put the code on line 2, I have to move the cursor to the semi-colon then type `"fp`. If I were to do this with the `:put` command (e.g., `:2put f`) the anonymous function would be placed after line 2.

Is it possible to use the `:put` command to put content mid-line or at a mark? Or is there an alternative (or better) way of doing this (I guess I could jump using marks more...)?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not.
You'll have to use other means:

- go to the right position and use `p` or `P` normal mode commands thanks to `:normal` -> `:normal! P` for instance. You may need first to put your variable into a register.
- you could insert the new thing at cursor position also thanks to `:exe "normal! i".the_string`. But you may have to fight against automatic indentation.
- obtain the line with `getline(line_nr)` do your computations and write it back with `:call setline(line_nr, new_line)`. But that'll be extremely tricky to use if you want to move several lines, and if you have multi-bytes characters.
- use `:substitute` along with column specifications -> `:2s/\%42c./\=a_string_variable.submatch(0)/`. See [`:h /\%c`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5c%25c) and [`:h :s\=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3as%5c%3d). I suspect, you'll have to reindent what have been modified afterwards as well.

Answer (score -1):

Use `:[range]g/.*/put`

where `[range]` is what ex accepts (ie. `n,m`, `%`, `.,$`, etc.).

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! We use backticks for code formatting like `:[range]g/.*/put`. Also note that `:put` is always linewise, so it can't paste at a certain column...